# Análise sintática de "Era uma vez, em um país muito distante, ..."

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe

Olá! Como se classifica sintaticamente a palavra "tão"?

Segue a frase completa:

---

*Era uma vez, em um país muito distante, um mercador tão venturoso em suas atividades.*

---

Estou tratando a expressão "Era uma vez" como o verbo "Existiu".

- Verbo: "Era uma vez" (Existiu)
- Sujeito: "Um mercador tão venturoso em suas atividades".
- Núcleo do Sujeito: mercador
- "um": Adjunto adnominal referente à "mercador"
- "venturoso": predicativo do sujeito
- "em suas atividades": complemento nominal referente à "venturoso"
- "tão": ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O "tão" é um advérbio, que aqui enfatiza o adjetivo "venturoso", ou seja, ele atua como um [adjunto adverbial de intensidade](https://www.normaculta.com.br/adjunto-adverbial/).

Comment: Foi o que pensei de início, mas fiquei na dúvida porque achei que o adjunto adverbial só poderia completar o sentido de um verbo. Contudo, o link que você compartilhou explica que também pode completar um adjetivo ou outro advérbio. Valeu!